# Using a number calculated by a macro as a p{} column width within tabular

Tags: tables, macros, expansion

I'm currently trying to create a tabular that dynamically adjusts to some inserted text. For that, I've written this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\lengthof#1{%
    \setbox0\hbox{#1}%
    \the\wd0%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\lengthof{Some Text}}} Some Text \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, this doesn't compile correctly (it gives me the "Missing number, treated as zero" and "Illegal unit of measure" error codes). This is quite strange, because the lengthof-macro itself works without a problem. What am I doing wrong? I suspect that this has either something to do with expansion order or modes, but I'm unable to figure it out.

(Please note that I am well aware that there are packages which solve this problem, but I want to understand this without a package to get a better understanding of how TeX works internally.)

Comment: AFAIR `\begin{tabular}{...}` never expands the argument, so `\lengthof{Some Text}` never gets executed. You might solve it by executing it before the table, storing the value in a length variable and then use that length as the argument (untested)

Comment: @daleif It's worse than that. Without `calc`, the argument passed to `p` should be a length (after macro expansion), but `\lengthof` doesn't work by pure macro expansion as it needs assignments.

Answer (score 3):

the `p{argument}` expands to `\hsize=argument`, so in your case:

```
\hsize=\setbox0\hbox{#1}\the\wd0
```

but this is syntactically wrong, because `\setbox` is unexpandable TeX primitive and TeX expects a dimen at this point. But, if your macro is intended only for usage in `p` argument, then you can define it by:

```
\def\lengthof#1{%
    \hsize
    \setbox0\hbox{#1}%
    \hsize=\wd0
}
```

Now, the `p{\lengthof{abc}}` expands to

```
\hsize=\hsize \setbox0\hbox{#1}\hsize=\wd0
```

and this is OK and creates desired result.

The same trick can be used in OpTeX.

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\widthof{Some Text}}|} Some Text \\ some longer text\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know that this package + command exist. This question isn't about finding SOME solution to this problem, I want to know precisely why MY solution doesn't work, because I want to learn more about LaTeX internals.

Comment: `calc` changes the `\setlength` command so that it can handle the \widthof and internally the tabular uses `\setlength\hsize{#1}`.